# Formata Numero Java

Tags: java

Estou estudando java e fazendo uns exercicios. Estou fazendo um exercicio onde passei 2 valores para serem formatadoss, Porém quando eu executo o programa da o erro abaixo, se eu passo apenas 1 valor dá certo, mas com 2 dá o erro.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple
>   points    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown
>   Source)   at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)  at
>   TesteMain.formataNumero(TesteMain.java:37)    at
>   TesteMain.main(TesteMain.java:22)

Abaixo segue o codigo, caso alguém possa me dar uma dica agradeço

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        double salario = 4520;
        double resto = 0;
        double imposto1 = 0;
        double imposto2 = 0;
        double impostoAPagar = 0;



        if(salario > 4500){
            resto = formataNumero(salario % 4500); //guarda o resto da divisao de 4520 por 4500
            salario = salario - resto;
            imposto1 = (salario - 3000) * 0.18; // 
            imposto2 = salario - (salario - 3000) * 0.08;

            impostoAPagar = imposto1 + imposto2;
            impostoAPagar = formataNumero(impostoAPagar);

            System.out.println("Numero formatado: "+resto);
            System.out.println("Imposto a pagar: "+impostoAPagar);


        }
    } //Fim do main

    public static double formataNumero(double valor){
            double numeroFormatado = 0;
            DecimalFormat formatador = new DecimalFormat();

            formatador.applyPattern("###,###.00; (###,###.00)");

            return Double.parseDouble(formatador.format(valor).replaceAll(",", "."));



    }

}
```

Comment: Não sabia que podia formatar assim `applyPattern("###,###.00; (###,###.00)")`. Acredito que o problema seja causado pelo `replaceAll(",", ".")`. Ao chamar esse método seu número fica, por exemplo: `123.456.00`. Se convertermos para o formato br é como se ficasse `123,456,00`. Não pode ter duas vírgulas.

Comment: Hum interessante, então eu usei o replaceAll porque quando vou imprimir usando o println dá outro erro alegando sobre a virgula ai eu vamos dizer que converti de virgula para ponto pra dar certo a impressão.

Comment: Entendi. Mas se remover o `replaceAll()` e debugar, o valor da variável `impostoAPagar` está correto? Coloque um brakepoint na linha `System.out.println("Numero formatado: "+resto);` e veja o valor de `impostoAPagar`.

Comment: Vou verificar, na verdade eu mudei o codigo aqui e agora imprimi normal, agora apenas estou quebrando cabeça com o Exercicio porque o resultado não é o esperado pelos juizes kkkk pra mim tá tudo certo, mas como eles fazem varios testes não tá 100% certo, mas vlw pela ajuda...

Comment: Não entendi o por quê você pega um double, formata e depois retorna ele para um double. Se quiser ler uma string no formato pt_BR e transformá-la num número, use `NumberFormat instance = DecimalFormat.getInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));` e depois `Number parse = instance.parse(valor);`